# Splitting into Quandrants

Tags: java

I am trying to split my grid into four quadrants, but I keep getting errors. Basically, I am trying to say that my x coordinates are between 0 and 50 and same with my y coordinates.

Then from there, I want to split the grid with my x and y coordinates. My second x in the for code is saying I need to create a `method(int,boolean)`. And all my integers after the returns have errors as well. I am brand new to Java, so any help or insight would be awesome!

```
GridValueLayer habitat = new GridValueLayer("habitat", 0.00, true, 50, 50);
context.addValueLayer(habitat);{
    for (int x = 0; x >= 0, x <= 50){
        for (int y = 0; y >= 0; y <= 50){

           if(x > 0 && y > 0)
             return 1;
           else if(x < 0 && y > 0)
             return 2;
           else if(x < 0 && y < 0)
             return 3;
           else if (x<0 && y >0) 
             return 4; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors? What do you expect this code snippet to do? Why do you always return? Why is that in a code block? So many questions...

Comment: Why do you use a `for` loop if you plan to `return` on the first iteration?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no purpose in having the for loop because once you do `return 1;`, or any return, the whole method stops. What you can do is simply output the results there instead of doing return, or populate an object in an arraylist with the x and y coordinates. In any case, remove the return and output instead and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what the errors are (or exactly what you want the code to do), but I don't think the code you have there will compile. The for loop syntax is an initial condition, when to stop, and an increment separated by semi-colons. For the increment you gave a condition. You also left out a semi-colon and have an extra curly bracket by `addValueLayer`. I still don't think this code will do what you want it to but this is a place to try to work from.

```
GridValueLayer habitat = new GridValueLayer("habitat", 0.00, true, 50, 50);
context.addValueLayer(habitat);
for (int x = 0; x >= 0; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y >= 0; y++) {
        if(x > 0 && y > 0)
            return 1;
        else if(x < 0 && y > 0)
            return 2;
        else if(x < 0 && y < 0)
            return 3;
        else if (x<0 && y >0) 
            return 4; 
    }
}
```